# How can I Connect to SQL Server Compact through Power Builder?

Tags: sql-server-ce, powerbuilder

In addition to connecting to `SQL Server Compact`, how can I attach, detach the database through `PowerBuilder`code so the `exe` and `database` would work with any system?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PowerBuilder are you using?  Hopefully one with .NET available because the connection is really easy.

1. Add reference to System.Data.SqlServerCe.Dll to your project. (in SQL CE folder)
2. Add using for System.Data.SqlServerCe to the object having connection logic.
3. Add connection logic

   SqlCeConnection conn
    string lsConn, lsFile, lsException

   try

   ```
     lsFile = "2ndAmendmentWarning.sdf"
     lsConn = "Data Source=2ndAmendmentWarning.sdf;Password='JoinTheNRAToday'"
     conn = create SqlCeConnection(lsConn)
     conn.Open()
   ```

   catch (SqlCeException ex)

   ```
     lsException = ex.Message.ToString()
   ```

   end try

Of course your database files and passwords would be set dynamically...